# Rails Rendering Partial With a Local Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, partial

I need some help with a test application I am working on. I have this line repeated multiple times in my application so I decided to render it out as a partial. When I do I get an error saying that it isn't seeing the local variable. Here is what's happening:

```
= simple_form_for ([@user, @dogs]) do |b| 
        = render 'dogs/dogs-cats-partials/newupload', :dog => b, :user => b
```

Here's whats inside the partial

```
.form-group.required
  = b.input :title, autofocus: true, :class => "form-control", :required => false
.form-group.required
  = b.input :description, autofocus: false, :class => "form-control", :required => false
```

Here is the exact Error:

```
undefined local variable or method `b' for #<#<Class:0x007f2ae1d8a5a0>:0x007f2ae1b4dc60>
```

Thank you in advance for anyone who can help... been stuck on this for an hour : )

Comment: What is the exact error? Please post it in the question.

Comment: @pavan Just edited. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: what if you just use:

render 'dogs/dogs-cats-partials/newupload', b: b .... because you're sending the local variables "dog" and "user" that reference your simple form... not sure what the logic is behind that

Comment: wow... that's a facepalm... thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"b" was never passed to the partial. Try this:

`render 'dogs/dogs-cats-partials/newupload', b: b, dogs: @dogs, user: @user`